# overloading function, why it always call the one with integer input when wrong type occur

Tags: c++

I am kind of confuse about overloading function.

```
extern void function(int);
extern void function(char*);
function('a');
```

when I call function('a'), the function that call is function(int) not function(char*).
I am kind of confusing here. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: 'a' is not the same as "a".

Comment: but why it call function(int) instead of error.

Comment: You can't overload functions in C; you must be thinking of C++.

Comment: @MakaraPr Your question doesn't make sense, because C has no function overloading. If this is C++, don't tag it as C. Also, `'a'` in C++ has type `char`, which is an integral type, and not an array or pointer type. It is not the same as `"a"`, which is of type `const char [2]`, convertible to `const char *` (but still *not* compatible with `char *` due to the const-mismatch).

Comment: The value `'a'` is a `char` in C++ (an `int` in C), but can be promoted to `int` in C++, and therefore the function taking an `int` is the function that can be called.

Answer (score 4):

In C++, `'X'` is an integral type, a single character. `"X"` is an array of `const char`, terminated with `\0`, i.e. `"X"` would like `const char x[] = { 'X', '\0' };`.

When you use `function('a');`, you are therefore calling an integer overload, when you use `function("a")`, you would be calling a `const char*` overload.

However, you do not have a `const char*` overload, so your program would be ill-formed if the compiler is not too liberal.

Comment: \0 is the string terminator.

Comment: @RolandIllig: Whoops, sure it is.

Comment: @c45207: Argh, need more coffee.